# How to check if a user is logged in? Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, session, flask-login

i have a problem with a functionality of flask-login.
I need to create a system, that prevents multiple users from logging in on one account in the same time. The goal i am trying to achieve, is a way to check if the user is currently logged in, and deny access to people that are trying to log in if the account is already logged in. I was trying to use:

```
user.is_active
user.is_authenticated
```

But they always are displaying "True", here is the rest of the code: is there a property that changes after the users logs in/out?

````
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        login = request.form['login']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=f"{login}").first()
        if user == None:
            return "Non-Existing User"
        else:
            if bcrypt.checkpw(password,user.password.encode('utf-8')):
                login_user(user)
                return "Success"
            else:
                return "Bad creds."

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return 'You are logged out'```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any property but we can do it another way. You can store a token like thing in database with the user details.

```
class user(db.Model):
     [...]
     token = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

when the user login, you can generate a random hex or string and store it in database.

When user logout set token to `False`

while logging in the user , you can check if token is not False.

```
user = User.query.filter_by(username=user_input).first()
if user.token != False:
     // allow user to login 
else:
     //  don't allow him and show warning message.
```